# regression lines

Tags: r

I need to add regression lines for each different combination of two qualitative variables.
These are the models and the plot I made, but I have no clue on where to put these lines and how to do it.

```r
colors <- interaction(val1, val2)

shapes = c(16) 
shapes <- shapes[as.numeric(Sex)]

plot(years, value, main="Score by Time", xlab="Years", ylab="value", col = colors, pch=16)


lines(lowess(val1, val2),col=2)

model1<-lm(value~years+val1+v2)
summary(model1)
plot(val1)

model2<-lm(years~val2)
summary(model2)
plot(model2)

model3<-lm(yearse~val1)
summary(model3)
plot(model3)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite `ggplot2` is much more concise for this kind of example, I provide here the alternative using `R base plot` if you really want to use it.

I used the same `df` that the one @cardinal40 made:

```r
> head(df)
       value age  sex  race   sex_race
1 -1.8812801  20 Male White White Male
2 -0.4755058  21 Male White White Male
3 13.3137759  22 Male White White Male
4 11.3594325  23 Male White White Male
5 13.3529303  24 Male White White Male
6 24.8443766  25 Male White White Male
```

For the plotting, you can have the use of the `for` loop to go over all different groups, use `abline` to add the regression line of your model.

```r
df = as.data.frame(df)
level = unique(df$sex_race)
colors = c("blue", "red", "green", "black")
for(i in 1:length(level))
{
  if(i == 1)
  {
    plot(x = df[df$sex_race == level[i],"age"],
         y = df[df$sex_race == level[i], "value"],
         xlim = c(min(df$age), max(df$age)), 
         ylim = c(min(df$value), max(df$value)), 
         col = colors[i],
         pch = 16,
         xlab = "Age",
         ylab = "Value")
    abline(lm(value~age, data = subset(df, df$sex_race == level[i])),
           col = colors[i])
  }
  else
  {
    points(x = df[df$sex_race == level[i],"age"],
           y = df[df$sex_race == level[i], "value"],
           col = colors[i], pch = 16)
    abline(lm(value~age, data = subset(df, df$sex_race == level[i])),
           col = colors[i])
  }
}
legend("topleft", title="Legend", legend=c("White Male"," White Female", "Nonwhite Male", "Nonwhite Female"),
       col=c("blue", "red", "green", "black"), pch=16, cex=0.54)
```

[image]

**EDIT: Alternative for code writing**

Based on @StupidWolf's comment, you can obtain the same plot by doing:

```r
df = as.data.frame(df)
level = unique(df$sex_race)
colors = c("blue", "red", "green", "black")
plot(NULL, 
     xlim = c(min(df$age), max(df$age)), 
     ylim = c(min(df$value), max(df$value)),
     xlab = "Age", ylab = "Value")
for(i in 1:length(level))
{
  points(x = df[df$sex_race == level[i],"age"],
           y = df[df$sex_race == level[i], "value"],
           col = colors[i], pch = 16)
  abline(lm(value~age, data = subset(df, df$sex_race == level[i])),
           col = colors[i])
}
legend("topleft", title="Legend", legend=c("White Male"," White Female", "Nonwhite Male", "Nonwhite Female"),
       col=c("blue", "red", "green", "black"), pch=16, cex=0.54)
```

Here, thanks to @rawr, a more concise way to write the code to get the same plot:

```r
sp <- split(df, df$sex_race)
plot(value ~ age, df, type = 'n', xlab = 'Age', ylab = 'Value')
lapply(seq_along(sp), function(ii) {
  x <- sp[[ii]]
  points(value ~ age, x, col = ii, pch = 16)
  abline(lm(value ~ age, x), col = ii)
  })
legend("topleft", title="Legend", legend=c("White Male"," White Female", "Nonwhite Male", "Nonwhite Female"),
       col=c("blue", "red", "green", "black"), pch=16, cex=0.54)
```

Comment: Just a comment (you might already know this), you can do plot(NULL,xlim=..,ylim=..), then you iterate through the different groups. Saves the if and else

Comment: `split` would save a lot of work `sp <- split(df, df$sex_race); plot(value ~ age, df, type = 'n', xlab = 'Age', ylab = 'Value'); lapply(seq_along(sp), function(ii) {x <- sp[[ii]]; points(value ~ age, x, col = ii); abline(lm(value ~ age, x), col = ii)})`

Comment: @StupidWolf and @rawr thanks you very much for your comments ! I was not aware of these tips (I'm mainly using `ggplot2`) ;)

Answer (score 4):

The `geom_smooth` call in `ggplot2` can do this for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

white_men <- 3 * seq(20:40) + rnorm(n = 21, mean = 0, sd = 5)
white_women <- 2 * seq(20:40) + rnorm(n = 21, mean = 0, sd = 5)
nonwhite_men <- 2.5 * seq(20:40) + rnorm(n = 21, mean = 0, sd = 5)
nonwhite_women <- 1.5 * seq(20:40) + rnorm(n = 21, mean = 0, sd = 5)

df <- 
  white_men %>% enframe(name = NULL) %>% mutate(age = 20:40, sex = "Male", race = "White") %>% 
  bind_rows(
    white_women %>% enframe(name = NULL) %>% mutate(age = 20:40, sex = "Female", race = "White")
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    nonwhite_men %>% enframe(name = NULL) %>% mutate(age = 20:40, sex = "Male", race = "Non-White")
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    nonwhite_women %>% enframe(name = NULL) %>% mutate(age = 20:40, sex = "Female", race = "Non-White")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(sex_race = str_c(race, sex, sep = " "))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = value, color = sex_race)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]